# Separate Israel Visa for Vietnamese

Tags: israel

I'm planning to go to Israel after Lebanon and Pakistan. But I'm a Vietnamese so I have to apply for a visa in advance. But normally, the visa is attached to my passport. Can I get Israel Visa on a separate paper and not having it attached to my passport so that when I travel to Arab and Muslim countries, there is no proof to be found that I'm going to israel? Thanks!

Comment: Note that Jordan doesn't mind if you've been to Israel.